# Finding The Focus Point Of $y = \frac{1}{x}$

Tags: hyperbolic-functions

Hello everyone How can I calculate the focus point of $y = \frac{1}{x}$?

I converted the equation to $xy = 1$ and from there I tried to convert the function to something like this:
$Ax^2 + Bxy + Cy^2 + Dx + Ey + F = 0$
but I didn't success.

Comment: $A,C,D,E=0$, $B=1$ and $F=-1$?

Comment: Rotate it by 45 degree.

Comment: I know it rotated by 45 degree. How can I rotate $y = \frac{1}{x}$ by 315?

Comment: And how can i found the focus point if A,C,D,E=0, B=1 and F=−1?